# Android 4.0.4 Show Image From Remote Url?

Tags: android

I am trying to show an Image from remote URL using `ImageView` control

```
    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Set Image :

```
Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(Manager.URL());
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

It's working in android 2.2 and 3.2 but not working in android 4.0.4?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: It doesn't work on ICS and above because you're almost certainly doing the network request on the UI thread. For obvious reasons, that's not allowed (anymore). For solutions, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=networkonmainthreadexception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tanks .
My problem was resolved by this code

```
    public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return download_Image(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        _imgview.setImageBitmap(result);              // how do I pass a reference to mChart here ?
    }


    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        //---------------------------------------------------
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } 
        return bm;
        //---------------------------------------------------
    }


    }
```

and use in activity :

```
new DownloadImagesTask().execute(url));
```